# Query subselect at least one

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have a table named movement_history (that represenents movements of cars (register, sell, suspended, repaired, destroyed)). I want to get the information of a company 
that has sold each cars and to who.

This is my table (select *)

```
code_car  date_movement  type_movement  current_company_code
  6000     01/01/2010       NEW              5
  6000     01/01/2012       REPARATION       5
  6000     01/11/2015       SOLD             8
  6000     01/01/2017       DESTROYED        8
  4444     01/05/2000       NEW              10
  4444     01/05/2000       SUSPENDED        10
  4444     01/05/2015       SOLD             5
  4444     01/07/2015       RENOVATION       5
  4444     09/12/2015       SOLD             18
  ....      ...             ...              ...
```

So if i want  all the sales of cars from the company 5 in a determinated time (01-01-2015 to 31-02-2015) this would be the result:

```
  code_car  date_movement  type_movement  current_company_code
  6000     01/11/2015       SOLD             8
  4444     09/12/2015        SOLD             18
```

That's my query. First I obtain all the cars that someday have been from the company 5. Then I obtain all the 'SOLD' movements and I want to obtain for each car sold if some day has been part of the company 5.

```
select 
    code_car,date_movement,type_movement,current_company_code 
from 
    movement_history where code_car in (
        (select code_car from movement_history where current_company_code = 5)) and 
code_car IN     
        (select code_car from movement_history where type_movement = 
        'SOLD' and code_car <> 5 and date_movement > to_Date('01-01-2015','dd/mm/yyyy') and date_movement < to_Date('31-12-2015','dd/mm/yyyy'));
```

I guess am doing badly the part to obtain if each car sold  some day has been part of the company 5 al least one time.

Any suggestion? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What date is "31-02-2015" supposed to represent?

Answer (score 1):

I see.  The `current_company_code` is the company that *got* the car.  So, you want to use `LAG()`:

```
select mh.*
from (select mh.*,
             lag(mh.current_company_code) over (partition by mh.code_car order by date_movement) as prev_ccc
      from movement_history mh
     ) mh
where mh.type_movement = 'SOLD' and
      mh.date_movement >= date '2015-01-01' and
      mh.date_movement < date '2016-01-01' and
      mh.prev_ccc = 5;
```

Comment: Without using lag is ther any possibility?

Comment: @artyuiberwaf . . . `lag()` is the simplest solution and should have the best performance.  I see no reason not to use it.